# Visual Studio 2019 Angular and Typescript code coloring looks really bad

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I'm going through a Udemy tutorial for Angular *(Use Angular, Angular Material, Angularfire (+ Firebase with Firestore) and NgRx to build a real Angular App)* and I am using Visual Studio 2019 instead of VS Code, so that I can get more familiar with Visual Studio. So basically, I start a project from the Angular CLI, then open the containing folder from Visual Studio 2019.

1. (The picture above) Is this normal? That's a lot of white text! Which, in a code editor usually means it is telling me "I don't know what this is." When I open the same project folder in VS Code, I get what I would call a pretty rich color experience.
2. Searching online, there are a million VS Code options, but zero Visual Studio options, which makes me think it may be a setting in Visual Studio perhaps for Angular template files and .ts files?
3. As an aside, intellisense is really flaky for Angular and TypeScript for this project too. And blatant errors without red squiggly lines. Wondering if it is the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "Web Essentials" available in the marketplace, for anyone else that comes across this question.